# assign the ID of an agent in an assemble block in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4xE7.png)

hello,
i splitted agent 1 into agent 1 and a copy of agent 1 therefore i assigned an ID to the agent 1. Now i need to assemble agent 1 with agent 2 the new agent 3 needs to have the same ID like agent 1. So that in the end i can match and combine agent 3 with the copy of agent 1. I need help to find the right code to assign the ID in the assemble block to the new agent. Or a different solution to solve the Problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could try is to make a new variable, I might call it "tempID", then on enter 1 in your assembly block, store agent1's ID in tempID. Then to assign the ID to the new agent on exit of the assembly block.

Here's how that would look:

[image: anylogic code]

Comment: i always get following error message 

agent.id
"id cannot be resolved or is not a field"